# Java swing UI Threads and event button events

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, events, thread-safety

So as far as I understood, all the swing components should be created, modified and queried only from the EDT.
So if I happen to press a `JButton` "submit" let's say, that will pack up all the information from the text boxes, send that data to controller and then controller will send it to other controllers which will eventually send stuff to the server. What thread is the action for that button is running on? If it is running on EDT, how do I exit it to send the data to controller from the main thread? Should I even use main thread to send data to server from the controller?

So what I am saying is this

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // WHAT THREAD DO ACTIONS HERE RUN ON?
                // AND HOW DO I MAKE THEM RUN ON MAIN THREAD?
                // AND WHAT THREAD SHOULD I RUN THING ON HERE?
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `actionPerformed()` runs in the EDT. Whether the actions started there should run in EDT, and how to dispatch them to some other thread in case they shouldn't, is very much dependent on your application design.

Comment: for real, production code, without any side effects, actual bugs to use Runnable#Thread (is be re_usable, with endless loop too), output to Swing GUI (methods implementented in Swing APIs) must be wrapped into invokeLater

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any action triggered from Swing will run on the EDT. So the code in your `actionPerformed` method will already be executed on the EDT, without any special handling by you.

To start a long-running task, like sending data to a server, use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) or a `Callable` and an `ExecutorService`.

I prefer using a `SwingWorker` when implementing a Swing UI, as has it a useful API for publishing updates and makes the callbacks when the task is done automatically happen on the EDT.

Comment: Wow thanks so much. So pretty much as I understand it is, controller should access model and view using EDT and view can only access controller using SwingWorker right?

Comment: @Quillion No, I'd say all access of model, view and controller should happen on the EDT. `SwingWorker.doInBackground()` should do the heavy (time consuming) lifting, when accessing file system, talking to server etc., you typically initiate the worker from an `Action` (ie. command pattern).

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the picture I was seeking so that I could understand what to do and how to do it.